# How to get dynamic object property in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an object which is dynamic and its property values will change for different data.

eg : `MyObj = { country :"Ind", Place : "Pune"}`

Now I have one data value by which I can get first property which value I need to retrieve.

```
var MyArr = this.FiltArr[0].property;
```

This will return `myArr = country` and then later I will use like

```
MyObj.Myar = // my code..
```

This object and MyArr value is dyanmic. Obj may change and property of country may change to something else. Any idea how to achieve this?

Whenever I use MyArr I will get MyObj attribute which i need to play around. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `bracket` notation for this:

```
var MyArr = this.FiltArr[0].property;
MyObj[MyArr] = // my code..
```

**Bracket notation can use variables, so it is useful in your situation where the property names are dynamically determined (when the exact names are not known until runtime).**

Comment: Thanks, This is awesome